# Giving a double type for sqrt library function in C

Tags: c

*The C Programming Language* by Ritchie says that:

> The library routine `sqrt` expects a double type and will produce nonsense if inadvertently handled something else. So if `n` is an integer, we can use `sqrt((double) n)` to convert the value of `n` to double.

But the following code works fine on my system:

```
printf("%f",sqrt(9));
```

Then also it is giving the same result as `sqrt((double)9)`. Why is my compiler not following the book?

Comment: Because the C language has moved on and improved since the first version of K&R was published.

Comment: While a programming classic, I'm going to say that it's not a great idea to use K&R to learn production C.

Comment: @World Engineer which book do you recommend?

Comment: King's C Programming: A Modern Approach is good, so is C in a Nutshell if you're not learning programming for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you've declared the function prototype, `double sqrt(double);` .  (The usual way of doing so is with `#include <math.h>`.

If you have, then C will implicitly convert the function parameter to the correct type.  If not, the compiler will accept your code anyway, but the `9` will be incorrectly passed as an `int` instead of being converted to a `double`.

However, there are some compilers that treat `sqrt` as an [intrinsic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function), and “know” that its parameter is a `double` even if you don't declare it.

Answer (score 1):

because of implicit conversion, new compilers will upgrade some types to fit the target type,

int to double is one of the legal conversions

Comment: But why does the book say that ""The library routine sqrt expects a double type and will produce nonsense if inadvertently handled something else"?

Comment: because type conversion became standard **after** K&R was published

Comment: @ratchetfreak: I'd assume type conversion became standard after the first edition of K&R was published, but before the second edition of K&R was published.